# Prevent image to fly outside of the window

Tags: javascript, image

I have an image in my code that moves 750px every 5 seconds but it fly out of the page so you cant see it anymore. How do I prevent it to fly out of the page?

```
this is the code:
```

so far I tried to set the max width/height of the page but that doesnt work, I think you can solve it with tracking the image or something like that but I have no idea how to work that out.

Answer (score 1):

Use window.innerHeight and window.innerWidth if it's smaller than 750

```
function moveduck() {
  var top = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.min(750, window.innerHeight));
  var left = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.min(750, window.innerWidth));
  duck.style.top = top + 'px';
  duck.style.left = left + 'px';
  score++
};
```

Also, I don't think you need things other than top and left

Comment: thanks for the tip(Also, I don't think you need things other than top and left). I did add the code, now it doesnt fly out of the left and right anymore. but on the bottom of the page it still flies out of the screen